# Saving player's data from iPhone to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

I have an iPhone game, where, dunno, the player has like 3000 gold. Sweet.

Then his iPhone had some badass spontaneous combustion.

The player gets a new iPhone, but logically the game will reset him to 0 gold.
What method do you recommend me for saving such important data? Also, the data I might want to store can be a bit larger (loads of arrays containing important player stuff).

Thank you.

Comment: If his phone spontaneously combusted and then the guy went out and purchased another instance of the *same model phone that just exploded on him* then perhaps he deserves to have zero gold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the info you need in the application support directory for your app.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appSupportDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can write your arrays out to a plist file in this directory. Then if they choose to restore from a backup from the destroyed phone and they have made sure to sync their phone before they let it combust they will get their gold back.

Keep in mind that one could use the restore from backup feature to get to a previous amount of gold so you want to store their purchases and progress in a similar manor.

Also, depending on what you mean by "loads of arrays" you should probably consider using core data instead of plist files.  Your code will scale much better.  You can store your database in the same directory to get the same backup behavior.

Comment: Is an array with around 30000 elements (small strings/integers/booleans) considered a lot?

Comment: You should use Core Data for a data structure with 30,000 elements. However, the important point here is where you store the persistence file itself. If you put in the application support directory it will be backed up whenever the user syncs the device.

Answer (score 0):

Recently some apps tried to provide an option to sync data with dropbox. There must be some easy code snippets to do that. You could give an option to sync the save game data with Dropbox.

Comment: But then I would force every user to have a Dropbox account or something? Because it doesn't work for me if all players use one account (mine)

Comment: Well it depends on the scale, how many players you want to support.

Comment: Also yes, every user has to sync to their db account. Its optional, if they really care about their save game progress, they would do it :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use GameCenter or OpenFeint or both. In fact, most devs use both.

Comment: ... wait, no. Game Center is only leaderboards/achievements/multiplayer. I couldn't find anything about storing my own data. Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: GameCenter or OpenFeint is not used to store data or game progress.  Those are used to store achievement earned.

Comment: Well it all depends on what "3000 gold" means to you. If it's not achievement, you should probably store it in Keychain. Keychain data is not for storing s*** loads of data though. Use the documents directory to store raw data. This actually gets backed up to iTunes when the user syncs his device